# Burninate the [z-axis] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Burninate [z-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z-axis). No experts, searching for the tags isn't better than searching title/body, doesn't categorize questions better.

Comment: What? And go back to flatland? _looks for a pair of red/blue glasses_

Comment: Perhaps just make it an alias for `css`.

Comment: @stdere There's more than just CSS that uses 3D.

Comment: @stderr perhaps you're thinking of z-index?